# Pass entire array as local variable into partial, then render another partial with collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a layered partial scheme and am trying to write DRY code.
I need to pass a variable into a partial and maintain its array status so that within the partial I can render another partial with the `:collection` parameter.

**on this page I render the `'feed'` partial:**

```
 %div.row
    %div.span6
      %h1 Posts 
      /Post feed
      =render 'feed',:locals => {:feed_items => @posts}
    %div.span6
      %h1 Groups
      /Group feed
      =render 'feed', :locals => {:feed_items => @groups}
```

**Here is the `'feed'` partial:**

```
%ol
  -if feed_items.first.is_a?(Post)
    =render :partial => 'post_feed_item', :collection => feed_items
  -else
    =render :partial => 'group_feed_item', :collection => feed_items
=will_paginate feed_items
```

**Currently gives me this error:**

```
undefined local variable or method `feed_items' for #<#<Class:0x007fa8e2aa8b00>:0x007fa8e5405390>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

real error. final partial doesn't recognize component of the `:collection` passed to it:

```
undefined local variable or method `feed_item' for #<#<Class:0x007fa8e2aa8b00>:0x007fa8e2c6d670>
```

**final partial `'post_feed_item'`(layer 3?):**

```
%li.feed_item.row-fluid
  %div.image.span3
    =link_to image_tag(feed_item.assets.empty?  ? '/assets/small.png': feed_item.assets.first.image.url(:small), :alt => feed_item.title), post_url(feed_item)
```

So there is some problem in the first partial...`feed_items` isn't being parsed as an array?

Comment: you need to show the partial where the error is.  it looks like you are calling feed_item on one of your post_feed_item or group_feed_item partial which is not right.  the convention is the local variable has the same name as the name of that partial

Comment: ok let me try changing the local var name

Comment: wait, that means I need to make two `feed` partials. one for groups and one for posts

Comment: no. i think you misundertood. inside post_feed_item, you don't have access to a feed_item, instead you should use post_feed_item.  I think you can pass an `as` option to change the local variable name.  `render :partial => 'post_feed_item', :collection => feed_items, :as => :feed_item`

Comment: aHA! That was the issue. I want to blame rails conventions for this, but clearly I should have found that somewhere. Thanks much. Do you want to make a brief answer to this question so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling

```
= render partial: 'post_feed_item', collection: feed_items
```

will give you a `post_feed_item` local variable and not a `feed_item` variable. either you use that or pass in an `as` option to set the local variable name.

```
= render partial: 'post_feed_item', collection: feed_items, as: :feed_item
```

Comment: How do you pass `feed_item` as an instance variable?

Comment: if you already have `@feed_item`, you can just access it directly in your partial or pass it as a local variable `locals: { feed_item: @feed_tiem }`

Comment: Sorry my question didn't include the whole question's scale. I have a partial which expects an instance variable and an array with instances which I want to pass to this partial. Example: `collection: @items, as: :item` where `:item` should be ‘:@item`. (Last part doesn't work.)

Comment: post another question in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to render it as a partial:

```
 %div.row
    %div.span6
      %h1 Posts 
      /Post feed
      =render :partial => 'feed',:locals => {:feed_items => @posts}
    %div.span6
      %h1 Groups
      /Group feed
      =render :partial => 'feed', :locals => {:feed_items => @groups}
```

Comment: let me give it a shot really quick

Comment: yes, sorry, using your recommendation brings me back to the original issue, which I'd obfuscated with more errors in my quest for a solution. The original issue is that the 2nd layer partial doesn't accept the collection item being passed to it. Check out the edit

Comment: What's the value of `local_assigns[:feed_items]` in your feed partial?

Comment: Yea if you put a debugger statement in your view or just write it out in the HTML.

Comment: gives me two different statements like this: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fa8e3b61e10>`

Comment: thanks to jvnill above: The issue was that rails convention wanted local variables in the `:collection` param to be the same as the partial name. forgot about this. So I needed to add the `:as` param like so: `render :partial => 'post_feed_item', :collection => feed_items, :as => :feed_item`. Really appreciate your quick response though Shane. Much appreciated. Also the `local_assigns[:feed_items]` trick is a good pick-up